# «-Ому» — суффикс или окончание?

Tags: орфография

*-Ому* — суффикс или окончание?

> Мы пишем *по-своему, по-разному, по-иному, по-любому* потому, что, если мы используем *по-* с прилагательным, имеющим **окончание/суффикс -ому**, мы это всё по-дефисному пишем.

Comment: По-идее падежное же, а не суффиксное - дательным падеж, -ому/ -ему.